# Apache POI: Issue reading and parsing spreadsheet Date and time as LocalDatetime

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-poi

I am trying to read and parse a datetime using apache Poi utils.  I use a formatter on the apache poi cell.DateValue's toString function but keep getting a exception.

The Date that i'm getting the exception on:

6/20/2015  2:29:39 PM

Any idea what i'm doing wrong here?  I keep getting the following error.

java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Sat Jun 20 14:29:39 CAT 2015' could not be parsed at index 0

Any idea what the "cat" in the datetime string in the error means?

```
my code:

private val dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy  HH:mm:ss")

Parsing the cell value:
entry.createDate = LocalDateTime.parse(currentCell.dateCellValue.toString(), dtf)
```

Comment: The CAT is the time zone CAT – Central Africa Time. [Cell.getDateCellValue](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getDateCellValue--) gets a `java.util.Date`. And [Date.toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--) gets a string in format `dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy`. But why not simple using the  `java.util.Date`? Or get the `java.time.LocalDateTime` from that `java.util.Date`?

Comment: @Axel Richter Thanks please add that as the answer, how could I get the LocalDateTime from a Date?

Comment: "how could I get the LocalDateTime from a Date?": This question **is** answered multiple times already.